# Transition to a view controller with a custom animation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, transition

I am trying to create a scale animation for my view controller presentation

what i have is

```
UIViewController *vc =[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"nextVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[vc willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:vc];

    [self transitionFromViewController:currentViewController toViewController:vc duration:2 options:0 animations:^(void){
       vc.view.layer.anchorPoint = currentViewController.view.frame.origin;
        vc.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
        vc.view.frame = currentViewController.view.frame;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
   }];
```

now this code works, the view controller is presented.

but instead of doing the right scale i want, it comes flying in from the bottom right corner.

how do i make it sort of unfold from the top margin to the bottom margin